# How to get response from server as String ,Retrofit 1.9

Tags: android, retrofit, response

I would like to handle my response from server , but I don't know how JSON (from server) its looks like. So I tried to display response  as String , but I cant do it. Is it possible to display response as String? And then handle the response correctly. thanks

(Retrofit 1.9)

```
    LoginService loginService = RetrofitClient.createService(LoginService.class);
    loginService.searchOffer(getToken(), offerSearch, new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String offerSearchRequestResource, Response response) {
            String responseFromSercer = response.getBody();

        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your logcat/error you are getting when trying your code.

Comment: This is what Im getting ,"retrofit.client.Response@c7b4f16" How can I handle it? Thanks for qucik reply!

Answer (score 1):

change your response model to

> JSONObject (from Gson)

then in your

```
public void success(...){response.body.toString();}
```

like this:

```
 Call<JsonObject> call = YOUR_API_INTERFACE().YOUR_METHOD(YOUR_PARAMS);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, @NonNull Response<JsonObject> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseFromSercer = response.body.toString();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
            .....
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the request runs successfully and there is a response back...use

```
System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

i'd also suggest you add Logging Interceptors [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) so that you can get a detailed view of all your API calls

Comment: I'm sending something like that :

                String responeFromServer = response.toString();
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Response" + responeFromServer);

                And this is reposne: "retrofit.client.Response@c7b4f16" it that means something?

Comment: Try System.out as described above and show me the logcat response to it. I may also want to look at your server code to see how it handles the API call

Comment: In Android Studio i can only use Log.d to show logcat. When I compile the code I getting response in logcat like ""retrofit.client.Response@c7b4f16"                                                  
          String responeFromServer = response.getBody().toString();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Response" + responeFromServer);

Comment: Can i see the server code? and look at adding logging interceptors

Comment: This is my interface

    @POST("/offer/search")
    void searchOffer(@Header("x-auth-token")String header, @Body OfferSearchRequestResource offerSearch, Callback<String> offerSearchRequestResourceCallback);


    RetrofitClient:

    private static RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(API_BASE_URL)
            .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
            .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()));


    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        return createService(serviceClass, null, null);

Comment: why did you use void in creating your interface? you are telling retrofit to not expect a response.

Comment: I changed from void to String and now Im getting  errors like: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoginService.searchOffer: Must have return type or Callback as last argument, not both."

Comment: Don't use String...create a bean/serializable class..and use it ..hope you know it.

Comment: Yes , I know it , how to create  serializable class but my problem is , that I dont know how looks this class. I wanted to get response as String from server and check how this class looks and then build  serializable class. Yes , I know is hard to understand because Im beginner , but anyway ! Thanks for help!

Comment: Suppose your server response is a JSON like this {"status":"success"} the string success has been assigned a variable status in json..then create a serializable java class implementing status as a string variable and add set and get methods....then use the class in your http like this @POST("/offer/search) JAVA-CLASS-HERE...Everything should be OK mate